# iFrame displaying outside div in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a problem with a site displaying correctly in IE11. Everything is fine in Firefox and Chrome.
It is built using zen cart and the index page is made up of a series of html banners. One of these banners contains the code to display a twitter feed. In IE11 this is being output outside of the div it is supposed to be in.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to fix this issue. I tried adding an IE specific line in the stylesheet to move it up but it goes so far, until the top of the feed is roughly aligned to the bottom of the coloured heading next to it, and then one pixel more and it jumps up dramatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by removing the height and margin-top that i had set on the original div and then added new positioning to the stylesheet using the class in the embedded code provided by twitter. The additional css i added is just loaded up along with the embedded css.